# What to do with misspelled tag names?

Tags: discussion

There are currently three questions with the tag [cross-plattform](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-plattform).  This should be spelled [cross-platform](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-platform), but that tag doesn't currently exist.  What is the best way to handle this situation?  I don't think a tag synonym is the correct solution, because we only want one tag to appear when the user starts typing "cross-pl".  Should the three questions be edited to correct the tag spelling, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are just three questions, remove the tag and create a new one with the proper spelling.

In this case I think the tag shouldn’t exist at all, because it is ambiguous: what platform, browser, PHP version, operating system or something else? Shouldn’t all solutions work on any system? I’d say let’s just remove it.

Comment: Agreed. `<cross-platform>` is off-topic for WPSE, because WordPress has no *WordPress-specific* cross-platform issues.